# Need to show toastr on validation failed in Laravel Livewire 3

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

I am not too much familiar with Livewire concept. I have some error while working with this. So anyone can please help me.

**I have to show toast if there is an error while image uploading and also need to show preview. Also if request file is injected is better for me.**

app/Livewire/Crafts/Profile/AccountOverview.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Livewire\Crafts\Profile;
use App\Http\Requests\Crafts\AccountOverviewRequest;
use App\Traits\AuthUser;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
class AccountOverview extends Component
{
    use AuthUser, WithFileUploads;
    public $profile_image, $username;
    protected $listeners = ['changeProfilePhoto' => 'changeProfilePhoto'];
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->username = $this->authUser()->name;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.crafts.profile.account-overview');
    }
    public function changeProfilePhoto(AccountOverviewRequest $request)
    {
        if($request->validate()){
            // Insert Logic
            return $this->dispatch('toast', message: 'Photo updated successfully.', notify:'success' );
        }else{
            return $this->dispatch('toast', message: 'Error in photo upload..', notify:'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

account-overview.blade.php

```
        <div>
        <!-- start top secton -->
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group row"  autocomplete="off">
        <div class="py-4">
                <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                    <div class="relative mb-2">
                        <img class="inline-block h-28 w-28 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" src="{{asset('images/no-image.png')}}" alt="">
                        <div class="relative">
                            <input type="file" class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 opacity-0 cursor-pointer absolute inset-0 w-full h-full" id="profile_image" wire:change.self="changeProfilePhoto" wire:model.live="profile_image"  />
@error('profile_image') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                            <label for="profile_image" class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 w-6 h-6 text-white bg-primary focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-full text-sm text-center inline-flex items-center justify-center">
                                <img src="{{ asset('images/icons/edit-white.svg') }}" class="w-4" />
                                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    
        <hr class="h-1 my-4 -mx-4 bg-gray-300/50 border-0">
        <!-- end top secton -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show yor view and the error message

Comment: @Pippo I have added blade file and error is showing in span in blade. I want in toastr and I have used normal jquery query toastr for dispatchbrowserevent.

Comment: Ok, but you should tell wich errors do you get when you say "I have some error while working with this". The way you are managing the file upload seems wrong, using Livevire you can't use the Form Request, the trait WithFileUploads will manage the process. Moreover, have you already preset the code for managing the toastr or not? If so, post this too

Comment: Another useful information can be whether you have installed any specific package to use *Toastr* with Laravel or not

Comment: Ok. Sorry. @Pippo There is no error. Just I need error handling with Toastr.

Comment: I am not using any laravel package. I am using js library of toastr like we have with vanilla js.

Comment: If you need any more clearity then please tell me @Pippo

Answer (score 0):

To show Toastr message via the events dispatched by your code, you can add some javascript in your component:

```html
<script>

    document.addEventListener("livewire:init", () => {

        Livewire.on("toast", (event) => {

            toastr[event.notify](event.message);

        });
    });

</script>
```

Instead, for correct use of the *WithFileUploads* trait and for validation management you can look [here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/uploads) and [here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/validation)